# I want my vba code to lock my sheet after a certain time has elapsed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write some VBA code that will lock a sheet if a cell (A1) has a certain value. What I have currently:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("A1").Value < Date - 1 + (7/24) Then
        ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="mypassword"
        MsgBox "This workbook is locked, please contact...", vbInformation, "Protected Document"
    Else
        End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I enter the password to unprotect, it immediately protects again. I can see that this is just doing what I have asked. But what I want is when the password is correctly entered, something else should change so that the locking condition is no longer satisfied. Could someone help please?

---

Edit: Once I put in the password correctly, I just want this whole piece of code to be ignored after that.

Comment: You need another condition that verifies whether the active sheet is already protected then.

Comment: But once you put in the password, doesn't the sheet become unprotected again, just as it was initially?

Comment: Should it never lock again after being unprotected?

Comment: Not sure I follow. Entering the password correctly would unprotect the sheet, yes, and then adjust the timestamp in A1 accordingly, and once the condition is satisfied again the sheet will protect itself again on selection change, because that's what the code does. If you want to run it once and then never again, then you either need another flag somewhere that persists between sessions (saving it in a cell works), or write code that removes this handler procedure after it executed once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the condition evaluate whether sheet content is protected. `Worksheet.ProtectContent` returns `True` when that is the case:

```
If Not Me.ProtectContent And Me.Range("A1").Value < Date - 1 + (7/24) Then
```

That condition block wouldn't be entered when the sheet is protected.

Consider using the many specialized functions in the `VBA.DateTime` module to work with dates and times instead of doing potentially confusing date math with the underlying values.